# android Failed to pull selection

Tags: android

Android 4.1 emulator. When I'm trying to pull a file from DDMS-file explorer
Pull file under application databases directory(db file).

Got error: Failed to pull selection

I had try some way: 1. restart eclipse.  2. changed the directory permission

Any other developers got the issue?

Comment: in emulator give sdcard size.

Comment: I had set SDCard size, is 512M.

Comment: i am creating new android 4.1 emulator there was no problem .please re-create a emulator .

Comment: Thanks Android Revolution . I Created a new emulator, the issue is still exist. I will test at home, thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

Under DDMS click on emulator. It should be highlighted. Then try to pull the file, it will work.
Its eclipse bug.